# Trying to Send Email From Details View when insert button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook-2010, detailsview

i am working on a work order management web application where the user creates a work order. To create a work order i am using details view and to display it to the supervisor i am using gridview.

i have a dropdownlist field:

```
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type_of_Work_Order" 
                        SortExpression="Type_of_Work_Order">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("Type_of_Work_Order") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
     <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" DataTextField="Type_of_Work_Order" 
        DataValueField="Type_of_Work_Order" runat="server" Height="29px" Width="599px" 
          SelectedValue = '<%# Bind("Type_of_Work_Order") %>' 
                                onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                <asp:ListItem>Safety</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Quality</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>General</asp:ListItem>

  </asp:DropDownList>
 </InsertItemTemplate>
```

when the user enters all the information and clicks the insert button the data gets inserted into the database, but insert button is part of the details view but the new user requirement is that when the value is selected in the dropdown list and click on insert button i want to also be able to send an email to all the people but there is no button_click event for the insert button

Once i figure out how to get the button_click event fired up for the insert then i plan to do the following

```
if (DropDownList1.Text == Type of Work Order Selected By the User)
{
// Create a Outlook Application and connect to outlook 
Application OutlookApplication = new Application();

// create the MailItem which we want to send 
MailItem email = (MailItem)OutlookApplication.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
 // Add a recipient for the email
email.Recipients.Add("**PEOPLE UNDER THE TYPE OF WORK ORDER GROUP**");
 // add subject and body of the email
email.Subject = "Test";
email.Body = "This is a test email to check outlook email sending code";

// add display name, position and attach type for the attachment
string DisplayName = "MyAttachment";
int iPosition = email.Body.Length + 1;
int AttachType = (int)OlAttachmentType.olByValue;
 //now attached the file
Attachment Attach = email.Attachments.Add("C:\\test.txt", AttachType, iPosition, DisplayName);

//send email
email.Send();
}
```

**any help would be greatly appreciated**

Comment: Is that actually using Outlook interop to send emails, rather than `System.Net.Mail` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.Mail%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)???

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0) article.

Instead, you may consider using the System.Net.Mail namespace or low-level API on which Outlook is based on - Extended MAPI. If you deal with Exchange only, see EWS, [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx).